# how to use sliding divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 divs, they are both the height of the screen,the top div is called `button` and has a button en the bottom div is called `content` has some data.

I would like to hide the bottom screen in jquery, and when i click on the button on the top div i would like to slide the bottom div up so it kinda slides into the screen.

I dont want to have any scrollbars thou. Anyone know what the best way is to achieve this? 
ty in advance.

This is the code:

```
<div class="button>...</div>
<div class="content">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to include JQuery UI, you could use the slide effect with something like this...

```
$(
  $(".button").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
  $(".content").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
);
```

If you're using some sort of click event...

```
$(
  $(somethingYouWillClick).click(function(){
    $(".button").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
    $(".content").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
  });
);
```

[slide effect documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide#options)

Preventing the scrollbars would be a CSS issue I believe.